# jquery + loop through data attributes

Tags: jquery

I have a number of DIV's with the class mainMenuInternalTab

Each has the data attribute called data-pagename.

How can I loop through all instances of this data attribute to see there is one with the name converstations set?

thankyou

```
<div id="mainMenuInternalConversations" class="mainMenuInternalTab" data-pagename="conversations"></div>
<div id="mainMenuInternalConversations2" class="mainMenuInternalTab" data-pagename="conversations2"></div>
<div id="mainMenuInternalConversations3" class="mainMenuInternalTab" data-pagename="conversations3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to `iterate` through elements with class `mainMenuInternalTab`.

```
$('.mainMenuInternalTab').each(function(){
   alert($(this).data('pagename'));
   if($(this).data('pagename') == "convsersions set")
   {
      // do what ever you want here.
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (  
      $('.mainMenuInternalTab').filter(function() {
         return $(this).data('pagename') == 'conversations';
      }).length​
   ) {

         //do something if an element with the data attribute
         // pagename has a value of 'conversations'

     }
```

or a simpler version (but probably a little slower) :

```
if ( $('.mainMenuInternalTab[data-pagename="conversations"]').length ) {
    //do something
}
```